# Web Page shows as "waiting" even after code completes all the background process

Tags: c#

I have developed a web application which inserts records into PL/SQL using below code

```
trans_status = myDataAdapter.Update(ds, "LoadedTable");
```

The above update process takes around 30 minutes to complete the process.

All the code after `myDataAdapter.Update(ds, "LoadedTable");` gets executed without any issues but still the page is not get refreshed. The web page keeps on waiting and it never gives a message "Loaded Successfully".

All above happens on click of a button.

Step 1: Loads records from SQL server.[which takes around 14 sec]
Step 2. Insert all records fetched from SQL to oracle using myDataAdapter.Update(ds, "LoadedTable") [which takes around 30 minutes]
Step 3: Email notification to user [I am getting email notification]

```
transtatus = myDataAdapter.Update(ds, "LoadedTable");                  

            }
           if (transtatus == -1)
            {
                sql.SendStatusEmail("sample@abc.com", "Transaction Failed");
            }
            else
            {
                sql.SendStatusEmail("sample@abc.com", "Transaction 
                                 Successful");
            }
```

Step 4: Update some of the SQL tables with success/failure [All tables get updated successfully]
Step 5: Display the success message in label [Not showing anything as page is kept on waiting]

if (TranSuccess == true)
  {

lblMsg.Text = "Transation Successfull";

lblMsg.Visible = true;

Step 6: Load the grid with fresh records from SQL

gvFileList.DataBind();

gvProcessedFileList.DataBind();

}

Gridview bind in the last step in the click event.

In order to make sure the control is coming to the last statement I wrote a code to log some details into a plain text after gvProcessedFileList.DataBind(); , and I could able to find the result as well.

When I debug it works as expected, but When I deploy the code in the server only I am experiencing this problem.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you show the part of code .. Give more details like where are you show sucess message  is it a label or div inside updatepanel?. Or may be the  update is hapening in the DB server and It may be waiting for Response back...show more details

Comment: Most likely your request has timed out.  Look in chrome dev tools at the request and see what response is coming back.

Comment: @Sreenath Ganga